# Writing single bytes to a QDataStream

Tags: io, qt4

I want to write a series of bytes to a `QDataStream`.  When viewed in a hex editor, I'd like the resulting file to look like this:

```
0x DEAD
```

My attempt looks like this:

```
QFile file("test.txt");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QDataStream stream(&file);
stream << ((char)0xDE);
stream << ((char)0xAD);
file.close();
```

When I open `test.txt` with a hex editor, I can see that instead of writing these as single bytes, DataStream has left-padded them to full words, and the file looks like this:

```
0x FFFF FFDE FFFF FFAD
```

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The QIODevice left-shift operator (`<<`) doesn't have an overloaded definition for the `char` primitive, so it will cast it to an `int`.

It does have a definition for the `qint8` type.  Changing the code to look like this fixes the output:

```
stream << ((qint8) 0xDE);
stream << ((qint8) 0xAD);
```